# Who was Morgan Freeman writing the letter to?

Tags: plot-explanation, million-dollar-baby

In the movie Million dollar baby, Morgan freeman narrates what happened with Clint Eastwood and Hillary Swank. He was writing all this in a letter to someone.

I may have missed a few scenes in the beginning of the movie so I am just guessing that he was writing the letter to Clint Eastwood's daughter probably. Is that correct?

If Freeman was writing the letter to her to than where was she? Why would she read his letters? Was there a connection between them that I missed.

Clint Eastwood was often shown to be disappointed by the letters that were returned to the sender. He was storing them in a box in his cupboard. Why were the letters always unread. Was there a back story to this if there was any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Was there a back story*

We are never told what has happened between Frankie (Eastwood) and his daughter. All we know is that he writes weekly letters to her but they always return to the sender unopened.

> *I am just guessing that he was writing the letter to Clint Eastwood's daughter probably. Is that correct?*

Yes, it is correct. I haven't seen the movie for quite a while, so I had to make a quick search in the web. If you look at the last lines of the [**script**](http://www.ateliers-scenario.com/_media/million-dollar-baby.pdf) at page 120, Scrap (Freeman) says: *"I thought you should know what kind of man your father really was"*

As to why Frankie's daughter would read Scrap's letter ... well, just as Scrap, we have not a clue if she ever will. But he does it anyway because he just *needs* to tell Frank's story and wishes that the letter he's writing will reach her somehow.